# Make [lucene-index] a synonym of [lucene]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Lucene is a library used to build and search an index.  [lucene-index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lucene-index) adds nothing, and should be a synonym of [lucene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lucene).

There is already a suggested synonym out there.  Unfortunately, it has been hovering at 3 votes for about a year now, requiring me to occasionally grit my teeth in it's direction.

Comment: I don't know anything about Lucene, but indexing is a distinctive action. Why does it not deserve its own tag? Remember that question can have multiple tags. Not everything Lucene-related has to be lumped under a single [lucene] master tag.

Comment: @CodyGray Sure, but lucene *is* a search index.  This would be like having a [mysql-database] tag in addition to [mysql].  It is conceivable this could have been intended to refer to the act of writing data to the index, as distinct from searching, but in practice no such distinction appears to be present.

Comment: I just gave it the final nudge. (Should this be an answer?)

Comment: @larsmans either that or a mod marking this [meta-tag:status-completed].

Comment: @Tshepang posted with rationale.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I gave it the final push. Even though indexing is not the only thing Lucene does (retrieval being the other thing), everything it does *is* related to indexing in one way or another.